# Error in save() after an function in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to implement the `save()` method after the `self::restrictionMinimunBid($ request, $ karateka, $ bid)` function, but I get the following error: `"Method App\\Http\\Controllers\\BidController::save does not exist."`

Here is my code:

```
$bid = Bid::where('id_participants', '=', $request->id_participant)
        ->where('id_karatekas', '=',$market->id_karatekas)
        ->where('bid', '=',$request->bid);

        if(!$bid->count()){
         $bid->id_market = $market->id;
         $bid->id_group = $market->id_group;
         $bid->id_karatekas = $market->id_karatekas;                        
         $bid->id_participants = $request->id_participant;                                    
         self::restrictionMinimunBid($request, $karateka, $bid);
         $bid->save();                                    
         $response = array('code' => 200, 'Bid' => $bid, 'msg' => 'Bid created'); 
         }else{
         $response = array('code' => 400, 'error_msg' => "Bid already registered.");
         }
 public function restrictionMinimunBid(Request & $request, $karateka, & $bid)
    {
        $allKaratekas = Karateka::all()
        ->map(function ($allKaratekas) use ($karateka, $request, $bid){
                if($karateka->id == $allKaratekas->id ){
                   if($request->bid > $allKaratekas->value){
                    $bid->bid = $request->bid;
                    $msg ="The bid is more than the value of karateka";
                    var_dump($msg);

                   }
                   else{
                       $error ="The bid is less than the value ofmkarateka";
                       var_dump($error);
                   }
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($bid)` and check what it actually contains. It looks like it should be a collection and not a single model. If you want to add a new bid if none were found, try creating a new object:`$bid = new Bid()` in your if-statement instead of trying to add values to an empty collection.

Comment: Yes I do ```$bid = new Bid()``` before this code. And also ```var_dump($bid)``` and I receive the collection.

Comment: I already fixed the code, it was necessary to change the variable ```$ bid```, where I do the` `` where () ```.

Comment: all the code above `restrictionMinimunBid` is it in a method? can you provide the full controller code?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this one:

```
$bid = Bid::where('id_participants', '=', $request->id_participant)
    ->where('id_karatekas', '=',$market->id_karatekas)
    ->where('bid', '=',$request->bid);
```

To this:

```
$bid = Bid::where('id_participants', '=', $request->id_participant)
    ->where('id_karatekas', '=',$market->id_karatekas)
    ->where('bid', '=',$request->bid)->first();
```